# Use OSM data to a pwa

Tags: maps, openstreetmap, progressive-web-apps

I'm not very experienced on these platforms so I need your help.

I have edited and add various information in a specific place on OSM (Open Street Maps) and I would like to create a progressive web app which will withdraw these specific info and use the map to my app.

Any suggestions for searching material? I have in mind something like MAPS.ME app but in but in a much smaller range.

Thank you!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Did you already take a look at Leaflet or OpenLayers?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Google Maps API with the tiles from OSM. The PWA stuff is the same regardless of the MAps requirement.

More info: -

```
    var mapTypeArray = [google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, "OSM"];


    map.mapTypes.set("OSM", new google.maps.ImageMapType({
         getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            return "//b.tile.openstreetmap.org/" + zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
         },
         tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
         name: "OSM",
         maxZoom: 19
    }));
```